# Linking.canOpenURL returns true for IOS and false for Android : React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, command-line-interface, watchman

I have a simple string "twist" being passed on from the backend which is not a url[image of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxLvC.png)

My code for linking is as follows

```
console.log(url);     
let linkOpened = false;     
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((canOpen) => {       
console.log("canOpen : ", canOpen);       
if (canOpen) {         
Linking.openURL(url);         
linkOpened = true;       
} else {         
console.log("i am calling");       
}     
});
```

As we can see "twist" is a string and not a URL which cannot be opened.
The same code on android emulator returns false which is the correct result but true on IOS which is incorrect

[IOS Watchman Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK9YS.png)

None of the answers on github/stackoverflow/apple dev forums work for me

I have also added this in my info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twist</string>
        <string>nothing</string>
    </array>
```

Running on
XCODE 14
Node 165.13.0

Kindly assist me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Linking on backend using
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

It is directly linking ios nsurl TO javascript string which is causing error
for now use following code and wait for there update

```
const url = 'twist:';
console.log(url);
let linkOpened = false;
if (url.search(':') != -1) {
  console.log('url', url.search(':'));
  try {
    linkOpened = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
  } catch (error) {}
}

console.log('linkOpened', linkOpened);
```